# WordPress WXR file import partial fail: how to debug?

Tags: wordpress, import, xml-parsing

I am converting an old CMS to WordPress. Given that I have control over the source database, I have written a conversion script that generates a WXR formatted XML file. The import is partially successful, including comments, media, categories, etc. But several posts fail to import with no reason given. PHP error log shows no errors. How can I trace what goes wrong?

Comment: What I can deduce is that whenever a post is _not_ imported its comments are not imported either.

Comment: Here is an example of the WXR of a post that _fails_ [link](https://pastebin.com/xX0fhHVf)

Comment: I've tested this on a second, completely clean, WordPress install (zero themes, zero plugins) and the exact same posts fail to import. I therefore deduce that it's something in the posts. I'm passing everything in as CDATA, but should I be checking for UTF-8 encoding or the likes? CRLF issues? Something else?

Comment: Issue was bad date/time formatting. Another user pointed me towards IMPORT_DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was bad date/time formatting.